# Swift enum cases with same name

Tags: swift

Let's say I have the following enum:

```swift
enum Measurement {
 case Volume(litre: Double)
 case Volume(millilitre: Double)
 case Length(cm: Double)
}
```

Then when I do a `switch` statement like so:

```swift
switch measurement {
 case .Volume(let val):
...
```

How can I differentiate between the two `Volume` cases?
Or is this really impossible, and I should have `VolumeLitre` & `VolumeMillilitre` instead?

Comment: *I should have `VolumeLitre` & `VolumeMillilitre` instead?* Millilitre is just a litre with the factor 1/1000, 1l = 1000ml, therefor you should have just on of the cases ad use the factor.

Comment: @vikingosegundo I know, this is just a made-up example.

Comment: these days you never know…

Answer (score 7):

You could create another enum that represent the volume:

```
enum Volume {
    case litre(Double)
    case millilitre(Double)
}

enum Measurement {
    case volume(Volume)
    case length(cm: Double)
}
```

Also, for enum cases, use lowercase

Comment: Good idea, and true about lowercases.